# Error when correlating two arrays using MMULT

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I'm getting the follow error, after trying to correlate two arrays using MMULT():

> ERROR: Function MMULT parameter 1 expects number values. But '' is a empty and cannot be coerced to a number.

It turns out that this only occurs when there are blank cells in the range. How do I make the following part of the formula ignore blank cells:
`ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT('E1:Sample'!$D$2:$K,TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(('E1:Sample'!$D$2:$K))))`

Many thanks!

Comment: can you share an example spreadsheet?

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(N('E1:Sample'!$D$2:$K),TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(('E1:Sample'!$D$2:$K))))
```

The N-function will 'convert' empty cells to 0, while maintaining the values found in the other cells.